# Save linq query as data table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatable

In c# MVC, I need to get the following "result" (var) in the data table.

```
var allCompanies = objentity.ExecuteFunction<SearchAvailEmployees_Result>("SearchAvailEmployees", lstParam.ToArray())
                            .ToList();

var result = from c in allCompanies select new[] { 
                            c.LastName, 
                            c.FirstName, 
                            c.Phone, 
                            c.City, 
                            c.PositionApplied, 
                            c.Status, 
                            Convert.ToString(c.CallDate.Value.ToShortDateString()), 
                            Convert.ToString(c.CellOrPager), 
                            c.Gender 
                        };
```

I tried the following code but it won't works. It gives the error as

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from c in allCompanies select new[] { 
                                            c.LastName, 
                                            c.FirstName, 
                                            c.Phone, 
                                            c.City, 
                                            c.PositionApplied, 
                                            c.Status, 
                                            Convert.ToString(c.CallDate.Value.ToShortDateString()), 
                                            Convert.ToString(c.CellOrPager), 
                                            c.Gender 
                                        };

DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Any alternate solution to save the linq query result in data table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it:

First I declare a new `DataTable` and add columns, in this :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
DataRow row = null;
```

Now I execute the desired query:

```
var query = from c in allCompanies select { c.LastName, c.FirstName};
```

Now I simply iterate through the query and fill a `DataTable`:

```
foreach (var rowObj in query)
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(rowObj.FirstName, rowObj.LastName);
}
return dt;
```

Still in my queries I am using 'join'-statements.

Answer (score 2):

First, create `DataTable` with correct schema:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof (string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
            // Add more columns
```

Second, select array of value object:

```
var result = allCompanies.Select(c => new object[] {
                    c.LastName, 
                    c.FirstName, 
                    c.Phone, 
                    c.City, 
                    c.PositionApplied, 
                    c.Status, 
                    Convert.ToString(c.CallDate.Value.ToShortDateString()), 
                    Convert.ToString(c.CellOrPager), 
                    c.Gender 
                }).ToList();
```

Third, loop to create new Row from `DataTable` and assign value to new Row:

```
result.Foreach(array => {
     var row = dataTable.NewRow();
     row.ItemArray = array;
     dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove [] after new, it to be like

```
var result = from c in allCompanies 
             select new { c.LastName, c.FirstName, c.Phone, c.City, 
             c.PositionApplied, c.Status, 
             CallDate = Convert.ToString(c.CallDate.Value.ToShortDateString()), 
             CellOrPager = Convert.ToString(c.CellOrPager), c.Gender };
```

Create DataTable here

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.AddRange( new DataColumn[]{ 
    new DataColumn("LastName" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("FirstName" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Phone" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("City" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("PositionApplied" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Status" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("CallDate" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("CellOrPager" , typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Gender" , typeof(string))
});
```

Fill DataTable using this result

```
result.ToList().ForEach(x=>{
   var row = dataTable.NewRow();

   row.["LastName"] = x.LastName;
   row.["FirstName"] = x.FirstName;
   row.["Phone"] = x.Phone;
   row.["City"] = x.City;
   row.["PositionApplied"] = x.PositionApplied;
   row.["Status"] = x.Status;
   row.["CallDate"] = x.CallDate;
   row.["CellOrPager"] = x.CellOrPager;
   row.["Gender"] = x.Gender;

   dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
});
```

Comment: now it gives the following error on both "convert.tostring() statements"

Comment: Which error, Is it NullReferenceException,? If it is then c.CallData.Value can be null.

Comment: sorry here is the error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Comment: Answer updated, assign these toString result in a member. check answer.

Comment: sorry again it gives the same error i mentioned in the question :(